# Morfik - suitability for medium-scale web enterprise applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, nhibernate, morfik

I'm investigating technologies with which to develop a medium-scale (up to 100 or 200 simultaneous users) database-driven web application, and someone suggested Morfik. However, outside of the Morfik company I can find practically zero community support - no active blogs, no tutorials, no videos, no books - and this is of some concern (especially when compared to C# / ASP.NET / nHibernate etc support). Deciding between Morfik (untried and not used widely AFAIK) and the other technologies I mentioned (tried, tested, used widely) is becoming a critical issue for my company.

Has anyone had success using Morfik in these kind of circumstances? What kind of performance did you achieve?

Answer (score 4):

Being a Morfik user for the last 2-3 months, trying to do a quite large project. I totally understand your concern.

The community is small, Morfik developers though try to help you and answer almost all your questions. It was one of my concerns before purchasing it, but it's not a big deal actually.

However, it lacks documentation and tutorials. Yes, there is a chm help file, but outdated and lacks in many ways. Not enough examples, you should figure a lot of stuff on your own. But they say, it's Morfik team's one of the first priorities in the upcoming release to enhance the documentation.

We chose not to use Firebird as the db (Morfik supports it natively) and going with Postgresql over ODBC. There are issues to overcome there too. We had to dive in and modify (override) our own security wrapper for postgre etc. But overall, Morfik integrates with it quite fine. You should be prepared to small annoyances though.

We chose to go with Pascal version, as it is the major language the developers use. But, oh I hate Pascal so much :) It had been 10+ years last time I used Pascal and it can be really annoying with the quirky code editor of Morfik.. I miss VisualStudio, or even Notepad++ as editor!

Since we started our app, I see new components and examples released quite frequently. Morfik team invested on a separate team that develop addons for Morfik, which is a good thing.

So, in terms of support (not community but staff) you should not worry. It's still far from being a mature product but it does the job. Our relationship with Morfik is a love and hate one. I am quite sure our big project will be successfully completed with Morfik, and I can do small enterprise solutions with Morfik very (I mean very) fast. But I would also really think again to use Morfik if we do a big project like we are doing now.

I hope I make sense :)

Comment: and after 20 hours of my original post, they released the updated documentation and 2.4 version..

Comment: Thanks for the response. What about Morfik's support for parallel development with multiple developers on the same project?

Comment: We are using svn for versioning. It is not integrated into Morfik. And Morfik has some problems (not really designed for multiple developers), the project file itself stores too much information and some files are automatically deleted or renamed on the disk. It's troublesome but not hopeless, there are workarounds. And Morfik guys say they will address these in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking at www.morfikwatch.com which a blog dedicated to Morfik.  There you will find links to a couple of Morfik user communities. You can then ask around.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd expect that if Morfik is actually used by a reasonable number of developers that someone will reply here on SO; and seeing as there are a total of less than 100 developers in the communities you link to it doesn't do much to reduce my concerns about lack of community use / support.

Comment: Why would you think that Morfik doesn't support n-tier development?  Morfik bases all its framework around web services.  It makes it extremely easy to create web service based applications.

Answer (score 2):

We use Morfik for a variety of purposes,  all intranet based.   We are looking at the migration of all in-house corporate applications being refactored into morfik applications.

Morfik is a new product, and as such, the community is still growing.   Although Morfik 1 has been around for awhile, Morfik 2 is the first version that makes it easy to develop plugins and other third party tools.    Now there are small websites starting to appear that create plugins and support Morfik. (http://www.pannonrex.com/ for example).

Morfik is in it's infancy yet offers a solution to be found nowhere else.   I would recommend it highly.   Just give it time and the developer community will appear just as it did for Delphi and the rest.

best regards

Dalton Calford
Distributel Communications

Comment: Thanks for finding your way from here...
http://forum.morfik.com/#posts/13147?UID=&ListStyle=Tree&OS=0
;^)
... but I'm after specific performance information for internet (not intranet) applications (sorry if I didn't make that clear). It seems that Morfik doesn't support n-tier development, for one thing; and that database connections to anything other than Firebird are done via ODBC. Is this acceptable in an enterprise web-app? I'm not sure.

Comment: You can use Firebird which is great database.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, when I saw 100-200 simultaneous connections, I immediately thought you meant intranet.   We average 300-450 concurrent users on our apps, so we do not consider it a internet based app until you look at a possible 5,000+ users.

The design criteria for such a system is very different than a system with under 1000 users.

When you approach such a system, you are looking at a cloud configuration.   As our company is a telecommunications company, and we are required by law to meet 5-9's service for our customers, we use firebird in all our back end processes.   Although we have used DB2, Oracle and other products in the past, Firebird has either been more reliable or outperformed the others.

With the about to be released Firebird 2.5 (now in rc 2 if you wish to play with it), you can use firebird as it's own middle tier, with one database connecting to multiple other databases to perform both DML and DDL actions.   You can have one Firebird database that has no tables whatsoever, just stored procedures, views etc.   That database can then surface the data from multiple sources without the client application knowing.   As the connection can be dynamically built within the stored procedures, you can have the backend databases change as needed without changing any front end code.  This allows you to load balance, have multiple web servers share a single cluster of databases etc.

So, I since Morfik supports Firebird intrinsically, I would say that yes, Morfik can scale well to a larger environment without trouble.   As for Firebird support, it has one of the most active user communities on the web.

From the point of view of Morfik, morfik is a great way to generate a web based UI while leveraging your existing developer base without having to learn a series of new languages.  But, it currently lets the developer use the tools for n-tier development without getting in the way.   I like that.   I do not want a tool that tries to be everything and in turn, does nothing well.

best regards

Dalton Calford
Distributel Communications

Answer (score 0):

Something that I am very concerned about is 3rd party components. GWT has a fairly large collection of components. We make extensive use of data grids that need to be data aware and very rich, meaning it needs to be able to do grouping and sub groupings and master detail relationships.

You must also be able to create new groupings on the fly.

We also make use of pivot grids a lot, so we need them as well, and a quick google search doesn't show any components that can compare to what is already available in GWT.

It is a pity though, since the Morfik development environment seems very integrated. The GWT environment is a bit funny to me, since I am used to the Visual Studio and Delphi environments, so the way Eclipse work is a bit foreign to me, especially when adding new components to the different designers and editors in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Morfik is quite limited web development environment for a very basic web development. Even if it gives some benefits in the very beginning in long term it will tie you up.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with Morfik for two years, you can undoubtedly make applications fairly quickly for the management that has design and maintenance is literally 3 clicks, but when you want to add a little more robust functionality can become a pain of head, without counting the inconvenience that is to adjust the reports, has little documentation and the components are the majority of paid.

If you want an app in a short time and not very robust Morfik is indicated, if you want something more I do not recommend it.